# GCDAsyncSocket bug

Tags: objective-c, ios, tcp, gcdasyncsocket

I got some errors if I want to Compile my program, I Don't know what happend I want to compile it on my iPad,I want to build a TCP Server on my iPad to read datas from the client. I am a beginner of IOS programming.
Thanks for Help!
Simon
[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i Think You didn't Added  [Security framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/_index.html). to Your project. Try to add and Run Again.

To add Security Framework Go to Targets-->Build Phases-->Link Binary with libraries then Click on (+) symbol and add the Framework.